# this.geometry is undefined when using tree-mesh-bvh accelerated raycasting and ifc.js

Tags: three.js, ifc

In a simple IFC.js application, loading IFC models (and fragments for that matter) fails with `TypeError: this.geometry is undefined` when accelerating the raycast using `three-mesh-bvh`. Removing that makes the application work again. I have tried with plenty of different IFC models, all of which work when removing the acceleration. Even the test models (Schependomlaan.ifc for example) fail when loading them.

Source of the app: https://github.com/gjkf/simple-ifc

app.js:

```
import { AmbientLight, AxesHelper, DirectionalLight, GridHelper, PerspectiveCamera, Scene, WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
import { acceleratedRaycast, computeBoundsTree, disposeBoundsTree } from 'three-mesh-bvh';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { IFCLoader } from 'web-ifc-three/IFCLoader';

//Creates the Three.js scene
const scene = new Scene();

//Object to store the size of the viewport
const size = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

//Creates the camera (point of view of the user)
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, size.width / size.height);
camera.position.z = 15;
camera.position.y = 13;
camera.position.x = 8;

//Creates the lights of the scene
const lightColor = 0xffffff;

const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(lightColor, 0.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(lightColor, 1);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 10, 0);
directionalLight.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
scene.add(directionalLight);
scene.add(directionalLight.target);

//Sets up the renderer, fetching the canvas of the HTML
const threeCanvas = document.getElementById("three-canvas");
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ canvas: threeCanvas, alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

//Creates grids and axes in the scene
const grid = new GridHelper(50, 30);
scene.add(grid);

const axes = new AxesHelper();
axes.material.depthTest = false;
axes.renderOrder = 1;
scene.add(axes);

//Creates the orbit controls (to navigate the scene)
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, threeCanvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.target.set(-2, 0, 0);

//Animation loop
const animate = () => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};

animate();

//Adjust the viewport to the size of the browser
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  (size.width = window.innerWidth), (size.height = window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = size.width / size.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
});

//Sets up the IFC loading
const ifcLoader = new IFCLoader();
ifcLoader.ifcManager.useWebWorkers(true, "worker/IFCWorker.js");
ifcLoader.ifcManager.setWasmPath("../wasm/");
ifcLoader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
  USE_FAST_BOOLS: true,
  COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: true,
});

ifcLoader.ifcManager.setupThreeMeshBVH(
  acceleratedRaycast,
  computeBoundsTree,
  disposeBoundsTree
);

const input = document.getElementById("file-input");
input.addEventListener(
  "change",
  async (changed) => {
    const ifcURL = URL.createObjectURL(changed.target.files[0]);
    // ifcLoader.load(ifcURL, (ifcModel) => scene.add(ifcModel));
    const model = await ifcLoader.loadAsync(ifcURL, (e) => console.log(e));
    console.log(model);
    scene.add(model);
  },
  false
);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>IFC.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" accept=".ifc, .ifcXML, .ifcZIP">
    <canvas id="three-canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I made this simple application to nail down the problem, but in a different (Angular) project I would really need the accelerated raycasting to ensure the experience is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with your call to "setupThreeMeshBVH()"

This is a proper call with a proper sequence

```
ifcLoader.ifcManager.setupThreeMeshBVH(
  computeBoundsTree,
  disposeBoundsTree,
  acceleratedRaycast
);
```

In your code, you had given "computeBoundsTree" as the second parameter whereas it should be first.